# Stop pending tiles requests in Openlayers 3!

Tags: openlayers

I have created a Main-map in OpenLayers 3 with a single layer.

I use 'setUrl' to change the layers sourceUrl, when I want to change the map:

```
 this.mainMapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.XYZ({ url: this.url })});
 this.addLayer(this.mainMapLayer);

changeMainLayerSource(id): void {
    this.url = "http://MyTileServer" + id + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg";
    this.mainMapLayer.getSource().setUrl(this.url);  
}
```

It works, but it doesn't abort/stop pending tiles when the url is changed.
If I change the sourceURL, while some tiles are still pending, the map disappear, until all the tiles are done loading.

How do I avoid this?

Is there any way, to stop/abort pending tiles?